# Why did Result filter get called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class CustomResultAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {}

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {}
}

public class CustomActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {}

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "NotIndex" };
    }
}



   [CustomResult]
    [CustomAction]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

To my understanding, *Result filters* should only contain logic that operates on results produced by action method  ( hence the reason we applied `CustomResult` to a particular action method ).

So I don't understand why is *Result filter* also called  when `NotIndex` is being processed, since `NotIndex` was not not produced by *`Index` action method*?

Thank you

Comment: @gnat: what research are you talking about?! I already did the research, hence how I know that Result filters get called even if result is not produced by action method! Know I'm asking why it is a good idea that REsult filters also get called for non-action method results